# Flex Air Android : Disable back button

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

In some modern devices, the back button on Android is pure software.
The classical method to disable the back button don't work for me [Disable back button](http://grindheadgames.com/handling-button-air-android/)

Is there any other solution (the manifest or else) to disable the back button on Android ?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `View` or `Application`'s properties and script:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    ....
    ....
    backKeyPressed="view1_backKeyPressedHandler(event)">


    // Add this to your <fx:Script> area:
    protected function view1_backKeyPressedHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
```